# Using FeedIron to remove links from TT-RSS feeds

Tags: json, regex

I'm trying to come up with a formula to remove all links from a feed's content. I'm using FeedIron on TT-Rss.

This is what I've got so far:

```
{
    "url": "example.com",
    "type": "regex",
    "pattern": "^(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$",
    "replace": " "
}
```

I'm guessing that's already wrong(it's throwing an "Invalid JSON" error), but then again I'm not specialized at all. I just want to be able to receive the feeds without random links in the article content. Be it media links or any kind of link.

Can someone please help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maintainer of Feediron here.

Feediron doesn't work on the Article stub that comes in the RSS feed. It fetches the page source and then you modify the returned data.

The reason it's throwing a Invalid JSON error is because you have to escape the special characters in your regex.

E.G. using the website: https://www.freeformatter.com/json-escape.html

```
^(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$
```

Becomes:

```
^(http:\\\/\\\/www\\.|https:\\\/\\\/www\\.|http:\\\/\\\/|https:\\\/\\\/)?[a-z0-9]+([\\-\\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\\\/.*)?$
```

Also your configuration is not a correct format the example regex config:

```
"example.tld":{
  "type":"xpath",
  "xpath":"article",
  "reformat": [
    {
      "type": "regex",
      "pattern": "^(http:\\\/\\\/www\\.|https:\\\/\\\/www\\.|http:\\\/\\\/|https:\\\/\\\/)?[a-z0-9]+([\\-\\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\\\/.*)?$",
      "replace": " "
    }
  ]
}
```

Also note in the Testing tab you need to drop the domain "example.tld": for it to work